# ScalaCheck generator for web URLs

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

Wondering if anyone had to do this in using ScalaCheck: Create a custom generator for spitting out large number of URLs. Actually there is a caveat to this that I want to test a service which accepts ONLY valid/working web URLs. I am thinking if I get a large number of valid external/WEB URLs in a file and somehow feed in to the custom generator, only can make this possible?

something like

```
val genUrls = for {
       url <- "URL1" | "URL2" | "URL3"
}yield url
```

does this sound like a reasonable and actually more importantly doable approach?

Comment: Why do you need real URLs? Are you actually going to visit the sites during your tests? What if one of them happens to be temporarily down?

Comment: Yes, a comment about the intent of the checks that this generator would support will possibly help you find an alternative solution. For example, if you intend to generate `Source`s, you can do that without network overhead and needing to know valid URLs.

Answer (score 0):

[UrlGen](https://github.com/yannick-cw/sane-gen/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/github/yannick_cw/urls/UrlGen.scala) seems to give that, since uses a list of [top urls](https://github.com/yannick-cw/sane-gen/blob/master/src/main/resources/urls/top_urls), but cannot find the artifact in maven repo anywhere. Raised an [issue](https://github.com/yannick-cw/sane-gen/issues/2).

**PS**

You can always add `.suchThat(exists)`, where *exists* does make sure the URL exists during the test or better yet do it once, before the start of the tests, i.e. making sure all [these](https://github.com/yannick-cw/sane-gen/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/github/yannick_cw/urls/UrlGen.scala#L9) guys exist.